# React useSearchParams hook causes the component to re-render, but the child components are not rendered?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have a component structure:
`index.tsx > App.tsx > Page1.tsx > Page2.tsx > Children.tsx`
The address of the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/demo2-22ryrt

I am changing the search params using the `useSearchParams hook` in the `Children component`, but the result of the component re-rendering confuses me.

I know that the `useSearchParams hook` will cause the re-render of the component, but I have checked the relevant information and it should be two cases, one is that all components are re-rendered, and the other is that the component that uses `useNavigate hook` is re-rendered.

But in my case, `App.tsx` and `Children.tsx` rerendered, but `Page1.tsx` and `Page2.tsx` did not. It seems to me that `Page1` is a child component of `App`, why is `Page1` not re-rendering?

Comment: Please provide a code example

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/demo2-22ryrt

Comment: @Buggies https://codesandbox.io/s/demo2-22ryrt